# cannot instantiate abstract class when submitting form

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a .twig file that has the form with the following code:

```
{% block section_contents %}

    <section id="main" class="aux manage signup clearfix">

            <div class="container welcome-back arvo-regular clearfix">
                Join the Mysite Community
            </div>

            <div class="container form-bg clearfix">
                <form class="content-form wrap" 
                action="{{ path('MysiteMainBundle_signup_additional_info') }}" 
                method="post" {{ form_enctype(additionalInfoForm) }} novalidate>>
                {% if formValid is defined %}
                        </br></br>
                        <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
                            <h4> Errors </h4>
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm.firstName) }}
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm.lastName) }}
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm.address.addressOne) }}
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm.email) }}
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm.shop.name) }}
                            {{ form_errors(settingsForm) }}
                        </div>
                {% endif %}
                 <div class="personal-details">
                    <div class="text-line clearfix">
                        <div class="sub-header">
                            First Name
                        </div>

                       {{ form_widget(additionalInfoForm.firstName, { 'attr': {'class': 'validate[required] arvo-regular' } }) }}

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-line clearfix">
                        <div class="sub-header">
                            Last Name
                        </div>

                        {{ form_widget(additionalInfoForm.lastName, { 'attr': {'class': 'validate[required] arvo-regular' } }) }}

                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="arvo-regular button green signup-button" />

                 </div> <!-- end login details -->   
                </form>
            </div>

        </section>

{% endblock section_contents %}
```

But then when I submit this form I am getting:

```
   Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Mysite\MainBundle\Entity\Document in /Mysite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php on line 172 Call Stack: 0.0011 659400 1. {main}() /Mysite/web/app_dev.php:0 0.0284 7412872 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /Mysite/web/app_dev.php:29 0.1012 13005672 3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle() /Mysite/app/bootstrap.php.cache:619 0.1013 13007328 4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /Mysite/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1568 0.1013 13007328 5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /Mysite/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1392 0.2212 28737544 6. call_user_func_array() /Mysite/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1428 0.2212 28738032 7. Mysite\MainBundle\Controller\SignupController->indexAction() /Mysite/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1428 0.2960 35454528 8. Symfony\Component\Form\Form->bind() /Mysite/src/Mysite/MainBundle/Controller/SignupController.php:49 0.2968 35509648 9. Symfony\Component\Form\Form->bind() /Mysite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:539 0.2971 35517024 10. Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\{closure}() /Mysite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:559
```

I am not entirely sure why. It surely has something to do with the document class.

EDIT:

Added some form code:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        switch ($options['mode']) {
            case 'login':
                $builder
                    ->add('email')
                    ->add('password')
                ;
                break;
            case 'shop_create':
                $builder
                    ->add('firstName', 'text')
                    ->add('lastName', 'text')
                    ->add('phone', 'text')
                    ->add('email', 'text')
                    ->add('address', new AddressType())
                    ->add('city', 'text')
                    ->add('state', 'text')
                    ->add('dni', 'text')
                    ->add('zipcode', 'text')
                    ->add('shop', new ShopType())
                ;
                break;
            case 'account_settings':
                $builder
                    ->add('profilePicture', new ProfilePictureFormType())
                    ->add('firstName', 'text')
                    ->add('lastName', 'text')
                    ->add('birthday', 'date', array('widget'=>'single_text'))
                    ->add('website', 'text')
                    ->add('biography', 'textarea')
                    ->add('email', 'text')
                    ->add('address', new AddressType())
                    ->add('shop', new ShopType())
                ;
                break;
            case 'additional_signup_info':
                $builder
                    ->add('profilePicture', new ProfilePictureFormType())
                    ->add('firstName', 'text')
                    ->add('lastName', 'text')
                    ->add('email', 'text')
                    ->add('address', new AddressType())
                    ->add('city', 'text')
                    ->add('state', 'text')
                    ->add('zipcode', 'text')
                    ->add('password')
                ;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('You need to select which type of user form type you want to use.');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here's the form code in the controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {    
        if ($request->hasSession()){
            $session = $request->getSession();
            $username = $session->get('username');
            $session->invalidate();
        } 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $userRepository = $em->getRepository('MysiteUserBundle:User');
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

        $additionalInfoForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
            'mode' => 'additional_signup_info'
        ));

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $additionalInfoForm->bind($request);

            if ($additionalInfoForm->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
               return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MysiteMainBundle_marketplace'));

            }else{
                return array(
                        'formValid' => false,
                        'additionalInfoForm' => $additionalInfoForm->createView()
                    );
            }
        }

        return array('user' => $user, 'additionalInfoForm' => $additionalInfoForm->createView());
    }
```

Comment: Surely the whole form isn't relevant. Couldn't you reproduce this with less code?

Comment: Looks like you entered `Document` as a `Form` entity class and it is abstract. Show us the form code.

Comment: I trimmed the html and still

Comment: @VadimAshikhman you mean the code to generate this form?

Comment: The code of `FromType` class used in this template. settingsForm and additionalInfoForm

Comment: @VadimAshikhman I've added the whole code that I have

Comment: Also the issue happens when I try to bind the request with the form  $additionalInfoForm->bind($request);

Comment: Yeah, the error says it. I didnt find anything wrong with these code snippets. Maybe it's in the user entity class? When the form binds request it tries to load all the user entity relations. Btw is this the whole code of the `UserType` class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27137/discussion-between-vadim-ashikhman-and-adit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `UserType` class. As @ArgumentNullException mentioned @adit forgot to check the instantiate of abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the php files.  Make sure you're not instantiating an abstract class, and/or every class that implements an interface have definition for all methods declared in the interface.

Comment: well the UserType here extends AbstractClass.. but I assume that is fine